# Организация ЧПУ на сайте

Tags: чпу

Вопрос чисто теоретический. У меня если 2 варианта организации ЧПУ (человекопонятный урл). Какой из них лучше и быстрей?

1. При создании страницы генерируется ЧПУ и записывается в БД, а где нужна ссылка вытаскивается обратно.
2. При загрузке страницы все ЧПУ ссылки генерируется на ходу (все ЧПУ однотипные).

Второй вариант желательнее, но пугает скорость.

Answer (score 1):

Может `mod_rewrite`?

Ну и + (при желании) хранить ссылки в БД, т.е. например, в таблице `news` - `primary key` не тупой `id int`, а, например, `varchar(50)`, по которому и будет к странице обращаться пользователь. Вот вам теоретический ответ на ваш вопрос...
В итоге, при грамотном подходе - получаем 100%ые ЧПУ, не теряя в скорости.

Answer (score 0):

Недавно делал нечто похожее, но с возможностью изменять это из БД.

Т.е имеем примерно следующуую структуру:

```
route_id
    pattern: /news/{action}/{id}
    pattern_params:
        id: \d+
        action: \w+
    pageTitle: News
    controller: MyControllerName
    action: myAction
```

при "компилировании" паттерна (заменяем парметр на решулярное выражение)
и анализируем текущий url - если cовпал - значит вызываем соответсвующий контроллер с акшином.

Обратный вариант - формирование url - тут всё проще, заменяем просто {...} на соответсвующие параметры.

В общим как то так.

Comment: Я бы поменял `id` и `action` местами, тогда `action` можно сделать необязательным, что порой полезно.